# In what situations does Query.execute() return null in DataNucleus

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have not added anything to my Database yet, thus the following query should return a result of **0** by my reckoning.

```
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Password.class);
    query.setFilter("password == :passwordParam");
    query.setResult("count(password)");
    query.setResultClass(Integer.class);
    Integer result = (Integer)query.execute(password);
    System.out.println("Result: [" + result + "]");
```

It returns `null`

Neither the javadocs, nor the result docs, say anything about this method being able to return null. My guess is that I did something wrong.

http://db.apache.org/jdo/api20/apidocs/javax/jdo/Query.html#execute%28%29
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jdo/jdoql_result.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried your code with DataNucleus I experienced a similar problem at first.

The bycode enhancer was not running. Once I enabled it the count became 0 has expected.

Perhaps you're having a similar problem.

Comment: Note: I deleted my previous answer regarding aggregates and the JDO standard as it wasn't really helpful anyways.

Comment: The other info was useful too, you should leave both. :)  But anyway, amazingly I think you are right. The enhancer was running for sure, I see it run every time I save a file, but I did a clean project and now I get the expected result for count... perhaps it somehow didn't enhance this one file and clean caused it to do all of them again. Anyway, thank you very much!